# SLF4j for android

Tags: android

I have been integrating logger facility using slf4j in android.I can able to write log successfully by using following methods

```
 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
 logger.debug("Some log message. Details: {}", someObject.toString());
```

,how ever i need to get the log file in order to send it to the server.

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the slf4j documentation for android says it is just a fascade that uses the native android logger to see the log info in DDMS.

if you want to upload logs you need to save them to a file or something like that. and then upload. See the java File writer methods and search also for ways to upload files in java,

if you want logging support that will handle sending error reports to a server there is a really nice library for android called ACRA. its excelent. you can post to google forms or post to your own server among some other really neat features.

[ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the following implementations of SLF4J:

1. [Android Logger](https://noveogroup.github.io/android-logger/) is the lightweight but easy-to-configure SLF4J implementation (< 50 Kb).
2. [LOGBack](http://logback.qos.ch/) is the most powerful and optimized implementation but its size is about 1 Mb.
3. slf4j-android, slf4android (on github.com).

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Android Logger- exactly what I was looking for. However, the link you have provided is incorrect. It can be found at:
https://noveogroup.github.io/android-logger/